# how to switch cameras with one button?

Tags: unity, c#

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class cameraswitch : MonoBehaviour {
 public Camera cam1;
 public Camera cam2;



void Start () {
    cam1.enabled = true;
    cam2.enabled = false;
    Button Button = gameObject.GetComponent<Button>();
    Button.onClick.AddListener(baz);
}


void baz () {
    cam1.enabled = false;
    cam2.enabled = true;
}
}
```

this is my code . how to switch between the cameras with one button . and Thank You.

Comment: Have you read up on Coroutines in Unity?

Comment: I see you've edited your question to change the content. Can you clarify whether your current code is successfully "switching between cameras with one button"? If not, in what way does it fail?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I didn't understand you wrong, inside `baz` function you should do this:

```
cam1.enabled = !cam1.enabled;
cam2.enabled = !cam2.enabled;
```

This way you reverse the previous state of the cameras.